# Flutter: CheckboxTile tick mark not changing

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use Checkboxtile in Flutter. However, tapping on it is not changing the state of tick.

Here is the code:

```
bool checkedValue = false;
    CheckboxListTile(
    title: Text("title text"),
    value: checkedValue,
    onChanged: (newValue) { 
                 setState(() {
                   checkedValue = newValue; 
                 }); 
               },
    //onChanged: (newValue) { ... },
    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,  //  <-- leading Checkbox
  ),
```

Why it is not working?

Comment: `bool checkedValue = false;`, is this line in the build method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you.

```
class CheckBoxCustom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckBoxCustomState createState() => _CheckBoxCustomState();
}

class _CheckBoxCustomState extends State<CheckBoxCustom> {
  bool checkedValue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          title: Text("title text"),
          value: checkedValue,
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              checkedValue = newValue;
            });
          },
          controlAffinity:
              ListTileControlAffinity.leading, //  <-- leading Checkbox
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think i am using similar code. But still got the error. Let me create a new file and try your code.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. Create a bool i.e. bool isChecked= false;

   ```
                                      Checkbox(
                                      activeColor: Colors.white30,
                                      checkColor: Colors.white,
                                      value: isCheck,
                                      tristate: false,
                                      onChanged: (bool isChecked) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          isCheck = isChecked;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    )
   ```